# Increase max zoom for large scale raster with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, scale, zoom

I'm serving a large scale raster (warehouse map) with `GeoServer`.
I consume the WMS in a `Leaflet` web client and coordinates are projected according to EPSG:3857.

But it seems that maximum zoom is limited and can't go beyond scale of 1/20000. Even with the Leaflet *maxZoom* variable set to 100 when I pass the zoom 18 no more tiles are displayed.

How can I configure GeoServer to increase its maximum zoom?

Comment: how did you configure the gridset on geoserver - the default mercator grid goes to level 30

Answer (score 1):

That was a `Leaflet` issue.

The `maxZoom` was not limited by GeoServer (as Ian Turton commented the EPSG:900913 gridset goes until level 30) but was restrained by the default Leaflet [L.tileLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#tilelayer) `maxZoom`...